# Routes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, routes, selecteditem, navigator

I'm new in Flutter and I'm building a Flutter app, and there are these routes that I create, it's almost working, the problem is when I return to the previous screen, that should return the HomeScreen(), instead it's return a previous screeb that is the LoginScreen().
I'm using Navigator.pushReplacementNamed in this case, if I use only Navigator.pushNamed it returns to the HomeScreen, but selected the wrong Text(),

```
int selectedIndex = 0;
```

final List categories = ['Chat', 'Contatos', 'Grupos', 'Chamadas'];

```
ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: categories.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                  context, '/${categories[index]}');
              selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 15,
              vertical: 30,
            ),
            child: Text(
              categories[index],
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: index == selectedIndex
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.white60,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  letterSpacing: 1),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
```

and my Main.dart

```
 routes: {
    '/': (context) => MySplashScreen(),
    '/Chat': (context) => HomeScreen(),
    '/Contatos': (context) => ContactsScreen()
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Best have a look at the corresponding [cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation).

Your confusion in this case is because if you use `pushNamed()`, your router is "stacking" routes, not replacing them. The back button then "pops" the stack. (This is what I most frequently use.) If you use `pushReplacementNamed()` this equals to a "pop" and then "push", so no "stack" is built up.

Also, `selectedIndex` is not changed when using the back button, that's why the text is still the same (and wrong, to you ;-)) in that case.